# Reactjs Firebase: Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _config_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm pretty new to react and firebase. I implemented a login/auth system with firebase, and I was trying to take this to the next level: implement a profile page with profile picture. I followed a youtube tutorial and it seemed pretty easy,but somehow I'm getting a firebase error, and I assume something changed since the release of that tutorial! I don't really know what is going on, please help me fix this and explain me like I'm 5!

(update profile picture file)
ProfilePicture.js:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useAuth} from '../authentication/AuthContext'
import upload  from '../../config/firebase'

export default function ProfilePicture() {
  const  currentUser = useAuth()
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [photoURL, setPhotoURL] = useState("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png")
  
  
  function handleChange(e){
        if (e.target.files[0]){
            setPhoto(e.target.files[0])
        }
    }

  function handleClick(){
        upload(photo, currentUser, setLoading)
    }

   useEffect(()=>{
    if (currentUser && currentUser.photoURL){
        setPhotoURL(currentUser.photoURL)
    }    
    

   }, [currentUser])  

    
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button disabled={loading || !photo} onClick={handleClick}>Upload</button>
      <img src={photoURL} alt="Avatar" className='avatar'/> 
    </>
    )
}
```

firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/firestore'
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage';


const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})


export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const storage = getStorage();
//storage
export async function upload(file, currentUser, setLoading){
  const fileRef = ref(storage, currentUser.uid + '.png')
  
  setLoading(true)
  const snapshot = await uploadBytes(fileRef, file)
  setLoading(false)
  alert("Uploaded File!")
}

export const createUserDocument = async (user, additionalData) => {
  if (!user) return;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

  const snapshot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    const { email } = user;
    const { displayName } = additionalData;

    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error creating user', error);
    }
  }
};


export default app
```

the error:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up firebase compat version with the latest firebase modular version

The following lines are not needed.

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

You may want to revisit the documentation, and only follow the codes under version 9 **modular**.

For example, to initialize the app, the correct codes for version 9 modular will be something like this.

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app"

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
  };
```

For authentication you need to use `getAuth`

For example

```
import firebase from 'src/firebase/firebase'
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth(firebase); 

export async function loginPassword(email, password) {
  return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email,password) 
     
}
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth
Please follow the codes from v9 modular

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get this error whenever I try to upload an image to my firebase storage. What is causing it specifically? Is it the way I implement the auth?

Comment: apparently what's causing the error is this line: export const storage = firebase.storage();

Comment: You are using the module 9 codes, or still using your own codes?

Comment: You do not use any more firebase.* codes. They are already out dated.

Comment: is there any guide I can follow to make this right?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files using the Modular examples